# Gatsby JS: Redirect blog posts to new path

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I want to transfer all the blog posts from the current path `/blog-post-slug` to a new subdirectory `/blog/blog-post-slug`.

Currently, I create all the blog post pages inside the gatsby-node file and I just have to add the prefix to create the new routes. However, all the previous blog post and their backlink will not be valid. That's why I want to redirect the old post to the new ones.

The blog is deployed at Netlify, if it helps somehow.

Is there a way in Gatsby to match the old path and redirect it to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the `createRedirect` action in the `gatsby-node` and these two plugins [gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect](https://github.com/nsresulta/gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect) and [gatsby-plugin-netlify](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-netlify/).

I added the following code in the gatsby-node file:

```js
   const oldPath = "/random-slug/";
   createRedirect({
      fromPath: oldPath,
      toPath: "/blog" + oldPath,
      isPermanent: true,
    })
```

After running the `gatsby build` command check your public folder. It should have been generated the _redirects file that includes all the desired redirects.

You can run `gatsby serve` to find out if it works correctly!